# -Xdisable-assertions and -Xelide-below not turning off asserts

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt, assert, scalac

I'm currently working on a Scala project, that is using SBT, and I'm trying to produce production build settings in which one of the conditions are all asserts are turned off. I simply added the line, to my build.sbt:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(..., "-Xdisable-assertions")
```

I'm running the logLevel at debug and I see the options being passed to the compiler, but when I run our program(its long running program analysis), I encounter an assert. Though by all signs *all* asserts should be compiled away. I've tried this with both diable-assertions, and elide-below, without results. If anyone could give me some pointers on what I'm doing wrong, that would be great. I've written a lot of Scala, but haven't used SBT much beyond some basic projects.

Comment: I feel that it could start working if you changed "+=" to "++=" in that line.

Comment: @Rogach weird that this won't lead to the compile error (at least, jroesch is not complains)

Comment: @om-nom-nom - Well, that *does* lead to compile error.

Comment: my code does actually have ++=, just a typo on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you run "reload" in sbt after editing `build.sbt`? Because I tried building a small project, and all assertions are happily compiled away. For the record, I'm using sbt `0.12.0`.

---

Here is the sample project I used:

```
btest/
├── [  86]  build.sbt
└── [  45]  Main.scala
```

build.sbt:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-Xlint", "-Xdisable-assertions")
```

Main.scala:

```
object Main extends App {
  assert(1 != 1)
}
```

Comment: I did, and it appears that everything is being properly recompiled, and that is why I'm a little perplexed at the results, I'll check it out some more, and get back to you.

Comment: So this morning when I got back to the Lab and started working again, I decided to downgrade from sbt 0.12.1 and apparently that fixed the problem.

Comment: @jroesch - It may be worth to file a bug in xsbt bug tracker.